# MS SQL Server Report Builder report where clause parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportmanager

I am working on a Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder report and I am running into a problem I cannot seem to overcome.

My report is a list of college classes. I need to be able to display either all the courses or only those courses that are general education courses.

There is a course attribute that can be associated with a course. All general ed courses have a course attribute that consists of # followed by 3 letters.

The solution seemed to be pretty simple by creating a parameter that would pass either #% or % into the WHERE clause of my query like this:

- WHERE factClassAttributes.CourseAttribute LIKE '#%' (Gen ed courses)
- WHERE factClassAttributes.CourseAttribute LIKE '%'(all courses)

What I did not count on is that some courses do not have a course attribute and using % does not include records with a null value for Course Attribute.

I then thought I would try setting up a parameter that contained the WHERE clause as one value and null as the other value. This generates a generic "rsErrorExecutingCommand" error message.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to accomplish this other than creating an identical report without the WHERE clause?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Either use an optional parameter:

```
WHERE ((@param1 IS NULL) OR (factClassAttributes.CourseAttribute LIKE @param1 +'%'))
```

Or dynamically replace the nulls:

```
WHERE ISNULL(factClassAttributes.CourseAttribute,'%') LIKE '#%'
```

Comment: That doesn't get me what I need and that is probably because my question and background to the question were not clear. What I really need to know is if it possible to pass the entire WHERE clause as a parameter in SQL Server Report Builder or if there is a way to write the LIKE clause to return null and non-null records.